# GET запрос Retrofit2, ряд вопросов

Tags: android, kotlin, get, retrofit2

Получаю ли я данные по коду ниже, смотрю в андроид студио профайл, в нем отображается что я отправляю запрос и что-то получаю
2)Как можно вывести полученные данные? Они ведь хранятся в POJO файлах на основе JSON?
3)Возможно ли используя библиотеку ретрофит загружать изображения и имеет ли это смысл или есть другие инструменты которые сделают это быстрее.

Основное код

```
class RegistrationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var Reberth:String
    private lateinit var MessageToMe:TextView
    private lateinit var editText1: EditText
    private lateinit var editText2: EditText
    private lateinit var editText3: EditText
    private lateinit var editText4: EditText
    private lateinit var textView1: TextView
    private var BaseUrl = "http://195.189.123.84/api/"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration)

        MessageToMe = findViewById(R.id.RTextView)
        editText1 = findViewById(R.id.RTextEdit1)
        editText2 = findViewById(R.id.RTextEdit2)
        editText3 = findViewById(R.id.RTextEdit3)
        editText4 = findViewById(R.id.RTextEdit4)
        textView1 = findViewById(R.id.RTextView)

        findViewById<View>(R.id.RButton1).setOnClickListener{postData()}

        findViewById<View>(R.id.RButton2).setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        })

        findViewById<View>(R.id.RButton3).setOnClickListener{getData()}
    }

    internal fun getData() {

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        val service = retrofit.create(GetInt::class.java)
        val call = service.Beru()

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<GetLots> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<GetLots>, response: Response<GetLots>) {
                Reberth = response.body().toString()
                println("${Reberth::class.qualifiedName}")
                textView1.text = Reberth
                println("Текст")
                Log.d("Tag", response.body().toString())
                Log.d("Tag", response.code().toString())
                Log.d("Tag", response.headers().toString())
                Log.d("Tag", response.message().toString())
                Log.d("Tag", response.raw().toString())
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<GetLots>, t: Throwable) {
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Интерфейс

```
interface GetInt {
    @GET("lots/?method=receive")
    fun Beru(): Call<GetLots>
}
```

Json

```
Pojo файл соответствует Json, использовал http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org
[{
"photos":[{
"ext":"jpg",
"name":"212cbffd6f5d1e23458f55eb8aecb589645f0af0",
"dir":"27602c2f4c975c014165e97b22004580d6671090da95d163e9b5fab3cfa89bdb1312e93b7ffb8a659ea8eb92c03a9ea2508ca9b1ddf6f517077a85aee6affe6f",
"path":"/static/lotPhotos/27602c2f4c975c014165e97b22004580d6671090da95d163e9b5fab3cfa89bdb1312e93b7ffb8a659ea8eb92c03a9ea2508ca9b1ddf6f517077a85aee6affe6f/212cbffd6f5d1e23458f55eb8aecb589645f0af0.jpg",
"url":"/lotPhotos/27602c2f4c975c014165e97b22004580d6671090da95d163e9b5fab3cfa89bdb1312e93b7ffb8a659ea8eb92c03a9ea2508ca9b1ddf6f517077a85aee6affe6f/212cbffd6f5d1e23458f55eb8aecb589645f0af0.jpg"
}],
"_id":"5d9d6d874cb9ca00124ac7ab",
"classification":{"name":"Монеты","value":{"type":"coins"}},
"name":"Лот",
"catalog":{"name":"Иностранные монеты из серебра",
"value":{"type":"silver","of":null,"to":null}},
"count":2,"date":"2019-10-09T05:17:59.376Z",
"cost":500,
"info":"Тутуту",
"__v":0
}]
```

```
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/roaJq.png
```

Comment: Вы и так выводите данные. Смотрите, видимо, не в профайлере, но в LogCat - там просто логи. А выводите и так в текстовое поле. Если вам объект GetLots нужен, то он, по идее тут: `response.body()` Изображения лучше всего отдельной либой - `Glide`, например. Также не стоит игнорировать `onFailure` метод - обязательно обработайте ошибки. Ну и код почти нечитаем из-за больших букв в именах методов - никогда так не делайте. В Java и Kotlin так не принято.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб LogCat смотрю, не просто же так добавил его, но ничего не выводит. Текстовое поле тоже остаётся пустым. Добавил print ln с обычным текстом, но не нашёл куда он выводит, буду благодарен если скажете в какой вкладке смотреть. Я не игнорирую, для начала просто хотелось бы данные начать получать. На счёт синтаксиса спасибо ибо правильный пример брать не с кого.

Comment: Похоже у вас запрос в сеть просто не выполняется. Иначе и в логах было бы всё и приложение бы, вроде, должно было бы упасть, т.к. вы в TextView не из главного потока текст назначаете. Проверьте, что у вас подключение к сети в манифесте разрешено + попробуйте слушатель нажатий для 1 и 3 случая как для второго сделать. И не очень понятно как вы в профайлере что-то видите. Приложите скрин этого дела, вдруг чем-то поможет.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Разрешение есть т.к у меня выполняются post запросы, картинку приложил, сейчас сделаю слушателей, если получу какой-либо результат добавлю

Comment: О, кажется я понял. У вас ошибка парсинга JSON. Вы не вывели ошибку в `onFailure` вот и не видите этого. Вам надо массив моделей указывать, т.к. в ответе именно он: `fun Beru(): Call<List<GetLots>>`

Comment: Проверю, но смысл в этом и правда есть, благодарю. Просто я сколько перечитал здесь на форуме везде советовали сайты которые json в pojo преобразовывает. И не подскажете здесь возможно комментарий как ответ отметить?

Comment: Комментарий никак не отметить. Но если дело реально в этом - проверьте и я в ответ это напишу)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, действительно в этом(+ надо убрать в коде попытку узнать тип переменной Reberth), только я вывожу на экран id(Поправьте если не прав) самой переменной, но контакт теперь точно есть, данные получаю, осталось их вытащить. Проблема решена.

Comment: То, что у вас в текстовом поле - результат вызова `toString()` метода вашего класса. Чтобы было информативнее - переопределите этот метод, выводя вручную что нужно или сделайте GetLots класс `data` классом, добавив `data` перед именем класса в его объявлении. Так toString автоматически сгенерируется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас сервер возвращает массив, засим именно его и надо указывать в типе возвращаемого значения:

```
fun Beru(): Call<List<GetLots>> //вместо fun Beru(): Call<GetLots>
```